# Control center microphone enabling/disabling rapidly + audio glitching

Tags: audio, control-center

MacOS Ventura 13.4, RME Babyface Pro, MacBook Pro M1 Max 2021

I've found a weird issue somewhere between my audio driver and coreaudio.  Regularly my computer gets into a state where the audio stops or glitches out, and I can see in the control center that the microphone is rapidly switching between enabled/disabled.  I can stop it by doing a soft reset (shutting down my DAW or something like that) but it's pretty painful.

It's not reproducible with internal audio, so I know it's something between the driver and coreaudio, but its hard to say where the problem is without some kind of debug logs and knowledge about the how the interaction works.  Can anybody suggest how to get more information, theories I can test, or ways to contact engineering at Apple?  I'm already trying to chase it down with RME.

Thanks

Comment: If it’s not exhibiting symptoms with internal devices, it’s highly unlikely to be a macOS issue.  This is likely an issue with the 3rd part driver for your RME or even the hardware itself.  Have you contacted their their tech support?

Comment: I have and am discussing it with them.  However, speaking from experience, when there's a problem in an interaction between two systems, the fault can lie on either side.  Best to attack the problem from two angles!

Comment: Actually no.  Good diagnostics is about probabilities and the process of elimination.  You isolate each element to ensure they are “known good”.  “Attacking from two angles” increases the time and effort spent diagnosing because it introduces extra complexity.